# Why java.util.Map value can be primitive array but not single primitive

Tags: java, dictionary, wrapper, primitive, value-type

Here are two examples

**Map value as Single value**

```
private Map<Short, Boolean> _Booleans = new HashMap<Short, Boolean>(); //works
private Map<Short, boolean> _Booleans = new HashMap<Short, boolean>(); //not allowed
```

**Map value as Array**

```
private Map<Short, Boolean[]> _Booleans = new HashMap<Short, Boolean[]>(); //works
private Map<Short, boolean[]> _Booleans = new HashMap<Short, boolean[]>(); //works!
```

Primitive wrappers are forced on single value, but primitive arrays are allowed, why is that?

Sub question: Is it possible to use single value primitives with a Map?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maps can only store `Objects`. Primitives are not `Objects` unless they are in a wrapper class (`Boolean` instead of `boolean` in your example).

Arrays are always `Objects`, regardless of what kind of data they contain. Therefore, they can be stored in a Map without any problems.

In Java, typically you should prefer using primitive values, as they are faster and smaller in regards to memory usage. However, there are some cases (like the one in your example) where the boxed type is more useful. In some cases (typically when using generics), [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) might take effect.

An important difference between a primitive and its `Object` counterpart is that the `Object` can be null. A primitive is NEVER null.

Comment: Thanks! +1 Do you know if Map<Short, boolean> booleans = new HashMap<Short, boolean>();  would be somehow be possible in Java, maybe other libs?

Comment: I don't believe it is. Java.Utils.Map uses generics as the key and the value, and generics can only be Objects. Of course, you could write your own implementation of a Map that takes exclusively `Short` Objects as a key and `boolean` primitives as the value, but that seems like a lot of work for very little (if any) payoff. Besides, I think Java will autobox the values for you (primitives will get wrapped to Objects, Objects get unwrapped to primitives) using the built in Map, so in this case there's no reason to force the Map to take primitives.

Comment: That's one of the top reasons I don't like about java. They try to force you to use their wrappers everywhere. Regardless of it is actually needed or not. Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 1):

as @Nik meantioned, Map stores only Objects (any class in Java)

Now for your question, why is array of primitive boolean can be stored -> it's because in Java (and many other languages as well) Array is an Object

```
boolean cc[]={true, false};
System.out.println(cc instanceof Object);//gives true
```

Note -> that is true, only because cc has an actual array in it, but if you put null to it -> it will not longer an instance of Object so:

```
cc=null;
System.out.println(cc instanceof Object);//gives false
```

Note 2 -> 
for your *subquestion*: You cannot use them directly
Consider this example:

```
HashMap aMap=new HashMap();
        int x=120;//int value of 120
        aMap.put("120",x);//parsed Integer with value of 120
        x=aMap.get("120");//compiler error - Type mismatch
```

One more thing, since you are interesting in this subject. I would suggest you a book called "Effective Java", by Joshua Bloch who by the way developed the Collections in Java, and Map is of course a collection.